# Convert from cyrillic to latin C

Tags: c, linux, string, utf-8

How to make function that convert from UTF8 Cyrillic to UTF8 Latin characters? I know that I should make character table, but my main problem is how to represent string (in C ,Linux OS)? As char* or int* ( due to size of UTF8 )?

```
void convert(unsigned char* str) {
    if(str[0] == 'A' ) str[0] = 0xd090; // Cyrillic A
    ...
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172133/utf8-vs-utf16-vs-char-vs-what-someone-explain-this-mess-to-me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace a `char` with an `int` (or `short`), as it won't fit in a `char`. Either read the latin characters into a `wchar_t` array, or use a separate output array for the Cyrillic characters.